# check if this combobox contain a specific

Tags: c#, combobox

```
cbxItem = new Dictionary<string, string>();
cbxItem.Add("ALL", "ALL");
cbxItem.Add("S", "S");
cbxItem.Add("H", "H");
cbxItem.Add("R", "R");
cbxItem.Add("C", "C");
cbxItem.Add("W", "W");
combobox.DataSource = new BindingSource(cbxItem, null);
combobox.DisplayMember = "Key";
combobox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

User will input text in combobox for autocomplete. If combobox doesn't contain the value that user input, it will show a message to warn user. The problem is I don't how to check if combobox contain a specific value that user input in the combobox. PLease any advice? Thank in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you want ? are you trying to say you want to check whether the value user inputs , is contained in the checkbox or not ?

Comment: Just check if the input does exist as value in the dictionary?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63811ah(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: " input some text" where?

Comment: User will input text in combobox for autocomplete ,but if input not match with any item in combobox, it will show message.

Comment: how do you want to display the message ?

Comment: with message box.

Comment: Sure that you want that? What if the user types the beginning of an item in your list? You wouldn't want to show a message box then. Given that you have items longer than one character.

Comment: I want to check it because if user click search button while text value in combo box doesn't match with any item in it, the program will throw a message error

Comment: So basically, you want validation and prevent the user from clicking a button (search) until all input is valid?

Comment: yes, that all I want. You have any idea how I can do it?

Comment: It would be better if you keep the search button disabled until the input matches one of the items. It's easier for the user to change the text until the search button becomes enabled, rather than to close a message box.

Comment: As far as I can see, this is winforms (you should add a tag for your UI framework) and I'm not to familiar with its details. I commented so you can search for the right keywords (validation) and possibly edit your question with your updated requirements so you have a better chance to get answers.